# How to decreasing a quantity with notifier

Tags: php, mysql

Hi Guys This is my newbie question...
I started learning php  three days ago...
This is my problem...
for example
I have a quantity 50 when I subracted  by 10  the value 50 became 40
and the notifier alert me that number is less than 50
but still subracted when I subract it again .....

Here is My codes

```
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$id = $_GET['id'];
$old = $_POST['quantity'];
$new = $_POST['quantity1'];

$total = $new - $old;


if($total < 50 ){

        echo "<h1 style='color: red'><center>CRITICAL LEVEL</center></h1>";
        echo "<script>window.open('inventory.php' , '_self');</script>";

}


else{

$uiqry = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE table_inventory SET quantity = ?  WHERE id = ?");

$uiqry->bind_param('ii', $total,$id);

$uiqry->execute();
$uiqry->close();
echo "<script>alert('Subracted');</script>";
echo "<script>window.open('inventory.php', '_self');</script>";


}

}
```

I want When I the value 50 and I subract it from 10 the value is now 40 and the alert notify me
and when i subract it again by 10 the value become 30 and the notify popup again
how to do this
thanks in advance..
Sorry for my tongue twister english.. :D

Comment: Just remove the ` else { }` clause and always do the UPDATE query.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $old = $_POST['quantity'];
    $new = $_POST['quantity1'];

    $total = $new - $old;


    if($total < 50 ){

        echo "<h1 style='color: red'><center>CRITICAL LEVEL</center></h1>";
        echo "<script>window.open('inventory.php' , '_self');</script>";

    }

    $uiqry = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE table_inventory SET quantity = ?  WHERE id = ?");
    $uiqry->bind_param('ii', $total,$id);

    $uiqry->execute();
    $uiqry->close();
    echo "<script>alert('Subracted');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('inventory.php', '_self');</script>";

}
```